# Slim 6pin connector

Tags: connector

I might be posting this on the wrong forum,but I've litteraly been searching the web the whole afternoon....

I'm searching for a small form factor 6 pin connector.
I found a [6pin female 3.5mm jack](https://www.google.be/search?q=5%20Pcs%20Black%206%20Pin%203.5mm%20SMD%20Stereo%20Jack%20male&safe=off&client=tablet-android-samsung&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiej5Kb1-bVAhVDblAKHRUrAsoQ_AUICSgB&biw=1024&bih=768#imgrc=upPGJ25Yjs6dIM:), but can't seem to find the male connector piece.
I also thought about a rj11 connector, but the female piece of this conne for tend to be pretty big.

It would be used to connect sensor wires from a bldc motor.

Comment: I don't trust surface mount connectors. Connectors are subject to high mechanical stresses, and through hole parts have a much stronger connection to the PCB.

Comment: There are wide ranges of tiny wire-to-board connectors in various pin counts where you can get the board end in SMT and the wire end using miniscule crimp contacts.  Readily available pitches range from 1.25, 1.5, 2.0mm - and of course 2.54.

Answer (score 2):

Questions seeking product recommendations are closed very quickly. You need to edit to ask a technical question.

3.5 mm jacks have three-pins - not six. Some have a fourth for microphone.

[image]

*Figure 1. A surface-mount 3-pole 3.5 mm jack socket.*

The ones you have linked to are 3-pole. Each of the opposite pins are connected by the bridge across the top. This is quite obvious in Figure 1. When soldered to the PCB the six-point fixture will be far more than twice as mechanically strong.

Answer (score 0):

That's a female 3.5mm TRS connector. It's usually used for audio. Digikey classifies them as ["Barrel - Audio Connectors"](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-audio-connectors/434?k=&pkeyword=&pv29=1&FV=ffe001b2&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250)